# uniqueness problem with ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Consider the initial value problem
$$
\frac{dy}{dt}=4t\sqrt{y}, \quad y(1)=1.
$$
This is clearly separable, and using separation of variables we solve
$$
\int y^{-1/2} dy=\int 4t dt
$$
which gives $2\sqrt y=2t^2+C$. After replacing constants and squaring, this gives
$$
y(t)=(t^2+C)^2
$$
as the general solution. Now, to solve the initial value problem, we consider
$$
1=y(1)=(1+C)^2=C^2+2C+1,
$$
which has the two solutions $C=0,-2$. Therefore we should have **two** solutions
$$ 
y_1(t)=t^4\qquad y_2(t)=(t^2-2)^2
$$
to the above initial value problem. My issue here is that, well, doesn't this violate the Uniqueness Theorem? (Recall, the Uniqueness Theorem says essentially that, for an initial value problem of the form
$$
\frac{dy}{dt}=f(t,y),\quad y(t_0)=y_0,
$$
if both $f$ and $\partial f/\partial y$ are continuous around $(t_0,y_0)$, then the IVP has a unique solution in a neighborhood of $(t_0,y_0)$.) **What am I missing here?**

Comment: When you squared the equation to obtain $y = (t^2+C)^2$, you introduced a solution corresponding to $-2\sqrt{y} = 2t^2 + C$.

Comment: Another way to deal with an initial condition is to put it into the limits of integration... 

$$\int_1^y p^{-1/2} dp=\int_1^t 4q dq$$

$$ \implies 2(\sqrt y -1)= 2(t^2-1)$$
$$ \implies \sqrt y = t^2$$

Comment: Ah, okay, thank you! I think I get it now. I suppose we could also argue that, since $\sqrt{y}=t^2+C$ we must have $t^2+C\geq 0$, and when $t=1$ this forces us to choose $C=0$.